# How to properly remove the CUDAResources paclet?

Tags: packages, cudalink

I have Mathematica 8.0.0.0 installed on my Mac, and while I tried to see what it could do with CUDA, it downloaded a large directory (~1 GB) named `CUDAResources-OSX-8.0.0.8` in `~/Library/Mathematica/Paclets/Repository/`. However, after the download, I tried to see what it would give but `CUDAQ[]` returns `False` on my system. Seeing that CUDA's not going to be useful on this machine, how can I reclaim this disk space? In other words, how to get rid of this downloaded data?

Comment: Why not try to make it work, contacting WRI if necessary ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks Most probably the graphics card doesn't support CUDA, here is the list: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CUDALink/tutorial/Reference.html#1803279895

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just check: `CUDAResourcesUninstall[]`

Comment: Thanks, sounds great… but it doesn't work! It left my 883 MB `CUDAResources-OSX-8.0.0.8` directory untouched… I don't know what it actually did :)

Comment: @F'x I was in your same situation and it worked in my case, I don't have any `CUDAResources` directory.

Answer (score 6):

*This is somewhat of a long comment on VLC’s answer…*

Okay, now I know *why* `CUDAResourcesUninstall[]` didn't do the job, though I still don't know how to work around it. Due to updating from 8.0.0.0 to 8.0.4.0 recently, it turns out that the new version of Mma installs a new version of the paclet, named `CUDAResources-OSX-8.0.4.1`. That's the one that `CUDAResourcesUninstall[]` then uninstalls. But the older (now useless) 880 MB directory is left in place, unfortunately.

Given that I don't know how to properly remove this stuff, I ended up blasting the entire content of `~/Library/Mathematica/Paclets/Repository` (most of which was probably related to the older Mma version). I hope Mma will not have me pay for this. I still don't understand why a minor version upgrade ends up leaving around 1 GB of old stuff on one's account…

Answer (score 5):

I found something relevant today (which I don't know if is well-known).

If you're using version 9.0.1, then there is a built-in function `PacletUninstall[ ]`, I guess it can be used to *properly* remove any paclets which are *properly* installed. And there are more functions like this. Just check `` ?PacletManager`* ``.

I discovered them in the installer cdf for [Remote Development Kit](http://www.wolfram.com/raspberry-pi/).

I deleted the "\Paclets\Repository\RemoteDevelopmentKit-0.0.2" folder manually. Later when I tried to re-install it, MMA seemed to think it had already been there. So I guess there is an index or cache or something recording all the installed paclets information, and manually deleting the folder doesn't really uninstall the paclet *properly*. It should be done like

```
PacletUninstall["RemoteDevelopmentKit"]
PacletInstall["RemoteDevelopmentKit"]
```

I hope this helpful.